# Change the format of an xml file to match a new .XSD schema?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have a code coverage xml file that I need to change to comply with a different .xsd schema to be interpreted by a program.  What is the best way to do this?  I've researched XSLT for this task, but I'm not sure if I'm going down the right path with that.  I have no experience with xml, xslt, or xsd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert data from one XML format to another XML format, **XSLT is usually the right choice**. However, it is quite a complex language and may be frustrating if you don't know it well.

If you basically just need to rename a few nodes in the XML, you'll be fine with some simple XSLT.

If you have XSDs of both formats, you may want to look into a mapping tool like Altova MapForce (somewhat expensive, there certainly are cheaper options out there) that allow you to map between the schemas in a graphical way instead of writing XSLT directly.

Comment: Thanks! Not what I wanted to hear, but at least I know where to start.