# Transfer XML data into new XML format

Tags: xml, xpath, transfer

I currently have a PDML file which I am looking to draw information out of and to put into a new XML file.

A packet looks like the following in PDML format:

```
 <packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="58">
   <field name="num" pos="0" show="22" showname="Number" value="16" size="58"/>
   <field name="len" pos="0" show="58" showname="Frame Length" value="3a" size="58"/>
   <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="58" showname="Captured Length" value="3a" size="58"/>
   <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Aug 26, 2014 19:15:06.203826000 GMT Daylight Time" showname="Captured Time" value="1409076906.203826000" size="58"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="frame" showname="Frame 22: 58 bytes on wire (464 bits), 58 bytes captured (464 bits)" size="58" pos="0">
   <field name="frame.encap_type" showname="Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)" size="0" pos="0" show="1"/>
   <field name="frame.time" showname="Arrival Time: Aug 26, 2014 19:15:06.203826000 GMT Daylight Time" size="0" pos="0" show="&quot;Aug 26, 2014 19:15:06.203826000 GMT Daylight Time&quot;"/>
   <field name="frame.offset_shift" showname="Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
   <field name="frame.time_epoch" showname="Epoch Time: 1409076906.203826000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="1409076906.203826000"/>
   <field name="frame.time_delta" showname="Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001294000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.001294000"/>
   <field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001294000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.001294000"/>
   <field name="frame.time_relative" showname="Time since reference or first frame: 3.484800000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="3.484800000"/>
   <field name="frame.number" showname="Frame Number: 22" size="0" pos="0" show="22"/>
   <field name="frame.len" showname="Frame Length: 58 bytes (464 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="58"/>
   <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 58 bytes (464 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="58"/>
   <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
   <field name="frame.ignored" showname="Frame is ignored: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
   <field name="frame.protocols" showname="Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp" size="0" pos="0" show="eth:ethertype:ip:tcp"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="eth" showname="Ethernet II, Src: 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83 (78:e4:00:f9:ea:83), Dst: 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70 (98:8b:5d:b9:50:70)" size="14" pos="0">
   <field name="eth.dst" showname="Destination: 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70 (98:8b:5d:b9:50:70)" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070">
   <field name="eth.dst_resolved" showname="Destination (resolved): 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" hide="yes" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070"/>
   <field name="eth.addr" showname="Address: 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70 (98:8b:5d:b9:50:70)" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070"/>
   <field name="eth.addr_resolved" showname="Address (resolved): 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" hide="yes" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070"/>
   <field name="eth.lg" showname=".... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)" size="3" pos="0" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="988b5d"/>
   <field name="eth.ig" showname=".... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)" size="3" pos="0" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="988b5d"/>
   </field>
   <field name="eth.src" showname="Source: 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83 (78:e4:00:f9:ea:83)" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83">
   <field name="eth.src_resolved" showname="Source (resolved): 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" hide="yes" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83"/>
   <field name="eth.addr" showname="Address: 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83 (78:e4:00:f9:ea:83)" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83"/>
   <field name="eth.addr_resolved" showname="Address (resolved): 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" hide="yes" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83"/>
   <field name="eth.lg" showname=".... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)" size="3" pos="6" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="78e400"/>
   <field name="eth.ig" showname=".... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)" size="3" pos="6" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="78e400"/>
   </field>
   <field name="eth.type" showname="Type: IP (0x0800)" size="2" pos="12" show="2048" value="0800"/>
</proto>
<proto name="ip" showname="Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.211 (192.168.1.211), Dst: 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)" size="20" pos="14">
  <field name="ip.version" showname="Version: 4" size="1" pos="14" show="4" value="45"/>
  <field name="ip.hdr_len" showname="Header Length: 20 bytes" size="1" pos="14" show="20" value="45"/>
  <field name="ip.dsfield" showname="Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))" size="1" pos="15" show="0" value="00">
  <field name="ip.dsfield.dscp" showname="0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)" size="1" pos="15" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="00"/>
  <field name="ip.dsfield.ecn" showname=".... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)" size="1" pos="15" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="00"/>
  </field>
  <field name="ip.len" showname="Total Length: 44" size="2" pos="16" show="44" value="002c"/>
  <field name="ip.id" showname="Identification: 0xdf54 (57172)" size="2" pos="18" show="57172" value="df54"/>
  <field name="ip.flags" showname="Flags: 0x00" size="1" pos="20" show="0" value="00">
  <field name="ip.flags.rb" showname="0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set" size="1" pos="20" show="0" value="00"/>
  <field name="ip.flags.df" showname=".0.. .... = Don&apos;t fragment: Not set" size="1" pos="20" show="0" value="00"/>
  <field name="ip.flags.mf" showname="..0. .... = More fragments: Not set" size="1" pos="20" show="0" value="00"/>
  </field>
  <field name="ip.frag_offset" showname="Fragment offset: 0" size="2" pos="20" show="0" value="0000"/>
  <field name="ip.ttl" showname="Time to live: 52" size="1" pos="22" show="52" value="34"/>
  <field name="ip.proto" showname="Protocol: TCP (6)" size="1" pos="23" show="6" value="06"/>
  <field name="ip.checksum" showname="Header checksum: 0x2256 [validation disabled]" size="2" pos="24" show="8790" value="2256">
  <field name="ip.checksum_good" showname="Good: False" size="2" pos="24" show="0" value="2256"/>
  <field name="ip.checksum_bad" showname="Bad: False" size="2" pos="24" show="0" value="2256"/>
  </field>
  <field name="ip.src" showname="Source: 192.168.1.211 (192.168.1.211)" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.211" value="c0a801d3"/>
  <field name="ip.addr" showname="Source or Destination Address: 192.168.1.211 (192.168.1.211)" hide="yes" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.211" value="c0a801d3"/>
  <field name="ip.src_host" showname="Source Host: 192.168.1.211" hide="yes" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.211" value="c0a801d3"/>
  <field name="ip.host" showname="Source or Destination Host: 192.168.1.211" hide="yes" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.211" value="c0a801d3"/>
  <field name="ip.dst" showname="Destination: 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)" size="4" pos="30" show="192.168.1.254" value="c0a801fe"/>
  <field name="ip.addr" showname="Source or Destination Address: 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)" hide="yes" size="4" pos="30" show="192.168.1.254" value="c0a801fe"/>
  <field name="ip.dst_host" showname="Destination Host: 192.168.1.254" hide="yes" size="4" pos="30" show="192.168.1.254" value="c0a801fe"/>
  <field name="ip.host" showname="Source or Destination Host: 192.168.1.254" hide="yes" size="4" pos="30" show="192.168.1.254" value="c0a801fe"/>
  <field name="" show="Source GeoIP: Unknown" size="4" pos="26" value="c0a801d3"/>
  <field name="" show="Destination GeoIP: Unknown" size="4" pos="30" value="c0a801fe"/>
</proto>
<proto name="tcp" showname="Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 59634 (59634), Dst Port: 199 (199), Seq: 0, Len: 0" size="24" pos="34">
  <field name="tcp.srcport" showname="Source Port: 59634 (59634)" size="2" pos="34" show="59634" value="e8f2"/>
  <field name="tcp.dstport" showname="Destination Port: 199 (199)" size="2" pos="36" show="199" value="00c7"/>
  <field name="tcp.port" showname="Source or Destination Port: 59634" hide="yes" size="2" pos="34" show="59634" value="e8f2"/>
  <field name="tcp.port" showname="Source or Destination Port: 199" hide="yes" size="2" pos="36" show="199" value="00c7"/>
  <field name="tcp.stream" showname="Stream index: 0" size="0" pos="34" show="0"/>
  <field name="tcp.len" showname="TCP Segment Len: 0" size="1" pos="46" show="0" value="60"/>
  <field name="tcp.seq" showname="Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)" size="4" pos="38" show="0" value="1d78544a"/>
  <field name="tcp.ack" showname="Acknowledgment number: 0" size="4" pos="42" show="0" value="00000000"/>
  <field name="tcp.hdr_len" showname="Header Length: 24 bytes" size="1" pos="46" show="24" value="60"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags" showname=".... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)" size="2" pos="46" show="2" value="2" unmaskedvalue="6002">
  <field name="tcp.flags.res" showname="000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set" size="1" pos="46" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="60"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.ns" showname="...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set" size="1" pos="46" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="60"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.cwr" showname=".... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.ecn" showname=".... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.urg" showname=".... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.ack" showname=".... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.push" showname=".... .... 0... = Push: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.reset" showname=".... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags.syn" showname=".... .... ..1. = Syn: Set" size="1" pos="47" show="1" value="1" unmaskedvalue="02">
  <field name="_ws.expert" showname="Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection establish request (SYN): server port 199" size="0" pos="47">
  <field name="tcp.connection.syn" showname="Connection establish request (SYN): server port 199" size="0" pos="0" show="" value=""/>
  <field name="_ws.expert.message" showname="Message: Connection establish request (SYN): server port 199" hide="yes" size="0" pos="0" show="Connection establish request (SYN): server port 199"/>
  <field name="_ws.expert.severity" showname="Severity level: Chat" size="0" pos="0" show="2097152"/>
  <field name="_ws.expert.group" showname="Group: Sequence" size="0" pos="0" show="33554432"/>
  </field>
  </field>
  <field name="tcp.flags.fin" showname=".... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="02"/>
  </field>
  <field name="tcp.window_size_value" showname="Window size value: 1024" size="2" pos="48" show="1024" value="0400"/>
  <field name="tcp.window_size" showname="Calculated window size: 1024" size="2" pos="48" show="1024" value="0400"/>
  <field name="tcp.checksum" showname="Checksum: 0xb388 [validation disabled]" size="2" pos="50" show="45960" value="b388">
  <field name="tcp.checksum_good" showname="Good Checksum: False" size="2" pos="50" show="0" value="b388"/>
  <field name="tcp.checksum_bad" showname="Bad Checksum: False" size="2" pos="50" show="0" value="b388"/>
  </field>
  <field name="tcp.urgent_pointer" showname="Urgent pointer: 0" size="2" pos="52" show="0" value="0000"/>
  <field name="tcp.options" showname="Options: (4 bytes), Maximum segment size" size="4" pos="54" show="02:04:05:b4" value="020405b4">
  <field name="tcp.options.mss" showname="Maximum segment size: 1460 bytes" size="4" pos="54" show="" value="">
  <field name="tcp.option_kind" showname="Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)" size="1" pos="54" show="2" value="02"/>
  <field name="tcp.option_len" showname="Length: 4" size="1" pos="55" show="4" value="04"/>
  <field name="tcp.options.mss_val" showname="MSS Value: 1460" size="2" pos="56" show="1460" value="05b4"/>
  </field>
  </field>
</proto>
</packet>
```

The root of the pdml file is `<pdml>`.

As you can see its massive and needs to be shed of lots of data that will not be used.

The data I need to retrieve is found in these locations in the packet:

```
 "pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='ip.src']/@show"
 "pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='ip.dst']/@show"
 "pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='tcp.dstport']/@show"
 "pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='tcp.flags]/@showname"
```

What would be the best way to create a new xml file whilst extracting these bits of information?

Preferably the tree would look like this:

```
<packet name= [@name='ip.src']/@show.value>
  <destination> [@name='ip.dst']/@show.value </destination>
  <tcpport> [@name='tcp.dstport']/@show.value </tcpport>
  <flag> [@name='tcp.flags]/@showname.value </flag>
</packet>
```

Some may notice the new packet style looks similar to psml but one difference is that it psml does not contain the destination port number which is needed later on. This needs to be done automatically as the original xml file is huge so manually altering or inputting this would take hours maybe days.

Any help, pointers, software would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think instead of "transfer" you mean "transform"; have you tried using XSLT? You've already got the xpaths for the data you want.

Comment: How big is "huge"? If we're talking megabytes then XSLT is feasible, if gigabytes then you'll need to use something that operates in a more streaming style.

Comment: Ok thanks, the largest file size I am working with it 150MB so XSLT should be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the format of an xml file to match a new .XSD schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045652/change-the-format-of-an-xml-file-to-match-a-new-xsd-schema)